# PromQL for K8s pods that are over the CPU / RAM limits

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I've deployed `kube-prometheus-stack` and default rules / alerts helped me a lot, but I need to create custom ones.
Specifically, I would like to get information when my pods are 50% (warning) or 70% (critical) over their limits.
For example, if limits are for my pod 1 CPU / 1 GB of RAM, I would like to fire alerts if the pod is using 1.5 vCPU or 1.5 GB of RAM

I know this requires combinining `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores` and `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes` along with something like `node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate` for current CPU usage of container, or `node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_working_set_bytes` but I don't have an idea how to divide these two metrics and get end result where the current usage is over limits

For setting up 50% / 70%, I would of course create two different alerts with different severity, but the PromQL statement is bugging me. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you want to see if a Pod  uses more recources than it __*requests*__? Because it's not going to use more that the limit. Because, you know... it's a limit. As for the answer, to divide one metric by another you need to use a common label they both have. For example: `pod_memory_usage / on(pod_name) pod_memory_limit`, 'pod_name' in the example is the common label.